# SQL Relay cannot starts instance

Tags: mysql, sql

I have installed SQL Relay 64 bit in Windows 10 using sqlrelay-binary-distribution but got the following errors when using sqlr-start:

C:\Windows\system32>sqlr-start -id testdb

Starting listener: sqlr-listener -id testdb -localstatedir C:\Program Files\Firstworks\var\

Starting 5 connections to testdb-0 : sqlr-connection -id testdb -connectionid testdb-0 -localstatedir C:\Program Files\Firstworks\var\ sqlr-connection -id testdb -connectionid testdb-0 -localstatedir C:\Program Files\Firstworks\var\ sqlr-connection -id testdb -connectionid testdb-0 -localstatedir C:\Program Files\Firstworks\var\ failed to load connection module: C:\Program Files\Firstworks\libexec\sqlrelay\sqlrconnection_mysql.dll sqlr-conneThe specified module could not be found. ction -id testdb -connectionid testdb-0 -localstatedir C:\Program Files\Firstworks\var\ sqlr-connection -id testdb -connectionid testdb-0 -localstatedir C:\Program Files\Firstworks\var\ failed to load connection module: C:\Program Files\Firstworks\libexec\sqlrelay\sqlrconnection_mysql.dll The specified module could not be found. failed to load connection module: C:\Program Files\Firstworks\libexec\sqlrelay\sqlrconnection_mysql.dll The specified module could not be found. failed to load connection module: C:\Program Files\Firstworks\libexec\sqlrelay\sqlrconnection_mysql.dll The specified module could not be found. failed to load connection module: C:\Program Files\Firstworks\libexec\sqlrelay\sqlrconnection_mysql.dll The specified module could not be found.

I have checked the file path C:\Program Files\Firstworks\libexec\sqlrelay\sqlrconnection_mysql.dll and I can be sure that the file is there but for some reason, the program just can’t find it!

Comment: Have you managed to solve/work around this problem? I have the same issue and seeing as there's no answer to your question after 9 months, I'm guessing we're in the dark?

Comment: No solution found, I gave up :(

Comment: I got mine to work. I struggled for a day or 2 but my biggest problem was Windows 10, when I moved and ran it on Windows Server 2008 R2, I got it working. The error I had which was the same as yours, was solved by installing the MySQL Connector/C 6.1. If it still doesn't work, then copy the .lib/.dll files from the MySQL connector install dir to the binary dir of SQL Relay. Hope you get it working should you ever try again o/

Comment: I'll try it, thank you :D